# Can I use Role and ServiceAccounts with several namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, service-accounts, bare-metal-server

I'm trying to connect my k8s cluster to my ceph cluster with  this manual:
https://akomljen.com/using-existing-ceph-cluster-for-kubernetes-persistent-storage/

I want to deploy rbd-provision pods into kube-system namespace like this https://paste.ee/p/C1pB4

After deploying pvc I get errors because my pvc is in default namespace. Can I do with that anything? I read docs and if I'm right I can't use ServiceAccount with 2 ns, or can?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Service account is namespaced object and it is limited to particular namespace only

Answer (score 1):

Service accounts can be granted permissions in another namespace.

For example, within the namespace "acme", grant the permissions in the `view` `ClusterRole` to the service account in the namespace "acme" named "myapp" :

```
kubectl create rolebinding myapp-view-binding \
  --clusterrole=view --serviceaccount=acme:myapp \
  --namespace=acme
```

Comment: Thx. Can I do like this with secrets you know?